# JavaScript array push after map - return the length of array?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand how this code below prints the number 2 here.

```
const arr = [{
  greet: 'hi',
}];

const arr2 = arr.map(obj => obj.greet).push('bye');

console.log(arr2); // 2
```

On my first thought, since arr.map(obj => obj.greet) will return [ "hi" ], by pushing 'bye' to this array, it should be ['hi', 'bye'].

```
const arr = [{
  greet: 'hi',
}];

const arr2 = arr.map(obj => obj.greet);
arr2.push('bye');

console.log(arr2); // ['hi', 'bye']
```

Unlike this, if I put them together, it returns 2 instead of ['hi', 'bye'] which seemed really odd to me. Could anyone explain this for me?

Answer (score 2):

Since the return value of `push` is the number of elements in the array, so the first example will show `2` while the second one will actually show the array contents.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 2):

Array push will return the length of the array, this is what you assign to `arr2`. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 2):

[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the length of the array after appending the element.

You can use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator to append to a new array:

```
const arr2 = [...arr.map(obj => obj.greet), 'bye']
```

Or [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
const arr2 = arr.map(obj => obj.greet).concat('bye')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are console.log() the .push, and not the content of your array.
.push() is a method, and if you stock it in a const or let, they will take the value of the .push() method (so the length), and not the value of the array.

You can check an exemple in the MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push